# How should I organize my controllers using SOLID methodology?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently developing a new system and I remembered a Laravel Brazil Hangout about **S.O.L.I.D**.

Thinking about that, I check my controllers and realized that are responsible for more than one activity, for example:

**ContactsController**

- CRUD
- Import contacts from other systems (csv)
- Search for a contact (basic filter and advanced filters)

So the problem is I don't know what the better way to organize it.

- ContactsController
- ContactImportController
- ContactSearchController

Something like this?

---

### Obs

- I'm using Laravel 4.1
- I'm not using repositories

---

*Sorry for my english*

Comment: If I was you - I'd spend a couple of dollars and do the SOLID course on Laracasts.com

Comment: I'm a paying user, anyway.. I'll watch right now.

Comment: Cool - then check out Jeff's SOLID course. He has a lesson on each part. Takes about an hour. That will explain how to do what you want better than any answer you will get here on StackOverflow for this type of generic question.

Comment: I second that Laracasts is a great resource!

Answer (score 0):

I think your base problem is that you don't understand what controllers are for. Controllers are only a "glue" if you will for getting data from models/services/etc and passing it on to the view.

With sole regards to your controllers, the OLID is more or less taken care of for you by Laravel. Your responsibility is to make sure the controller has only one responsibility.

On a less related note, tasks like searching contacts and importing CSV data are better suited to a service for that purpose. Your controllers in general shouldn't be responsible for processing any data outside the context of passing it from model to view.

Comment: I think that's exactly what he understands as his problems right now and asking for how should he go about dealing with it.

Comment: Yes, I know about single responsibility principle, I just don't know how to implement it. That's my question. Anyway, thanks.